# Partial template argument deduction or workaround for std::array?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdarray

C++17 allows us to have `std::array`'s template arguments deduced. E.g., I can write

```
std::array ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and `ints` will be of type `std::array<int, 3>`.

My question is: what if I wanted to specify only the type argument of the array but have the size of the array automatically determined?

The following does not work since it seems like all template arguments have to be specified:

```
std::array<size_t> sizes = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

My compiler complains and says: *'std::array': too few template arguments*.

Is it possible to have the size of the array determined automatically by template argument deduction? If not, is it possible to create an array by only specifying its type but not its size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trailing class template arguments not deduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528865/trailing-class-template-arguments-not-deduced)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done. But a helper method does the trick:

```
template<typename Type, typename ... T>
constexpr auto makeArray(T&&... t) -> std::array<Type, sizeof...(T)>
{
    return {{std::forward<T>(t)...}};
}
```

Usage example:

```
const auto container = makeArray<double>(-5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0);
```

Comment: See [`make_array()` in the library fundamentals TS v2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array).

Comment: See `std::to_aray` too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::to_array() directly:

```
std::array ints = { 1, 2, 3 };
auto int1 = std::to_array<int>({1, 2, 3});
auto int2 = std::to_array<double>({1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score 1):

If, I might be so bold as to expand on the Benjamin's answer. Conceptually one does not need always to be explicit about the result type.

```
template<
typename ... T,
typename CT = std::common_type_t< T... >
>
constexpr auto make_array(T&& ... t)
 -> std::array<  CT , sizeof...(T)>
{
    return { { static_cast<CT>( std::forward<T>(t) ) ...} };
}
```

Slightly simpler usage

```
constexpr auto std_arr = make_array(-5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0);
```

The issue here might be, we are not exactly certain, what type of the `std::array` we will get. Provided we do care about it.

```
const auto std_arr = make_array(-5.0, 0, 5.0, 10.0, 42.13f );
```

Over "here", using MSVC, the latest, I get std array of doubles. If one's bed time reading is ISO C++ standard doc, the one might be sure what type will come out of `std::common_type` from the tool chain in use.

For the rest of us, literal suffixes will help

```
  constexpr auto sizes = make_array( 1UL, 2UL, 3UL );
```

But why stop with numbers? One can collect quickly, into an array, instances from the same hierarchy. Not caring about the result type.

```
    {
        const auto exceptions = make_array(
         std::exception{"SE"}, 
         std::runtime_error{"RE"}, 
         std::logic_error{"LE"} );
    }
```

A bit useless but somewhat weird and wonderful. One thing thou remember: this is compile time situation. Thus, I might prefer:

```
   constexpr auto sizes = std::array{ 1UL, 2UL, 3UL } ;
```

To answer the OP's question directly.

[There is also](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array) C++20 `std::to_array`. For the exact result type and for a bit more comfortable usage:

```
  constexpr auto sizes = std::to_array<size_t>({ 0, 1, 3 });
```

Enjoy ...

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array and consider allowing the caller to override.

Comment: Ah, I was kind-of-a expecting someone to mention C++20 std::make_array ... my intention  was not to produce implementation that might compete with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, using nested templates.  You can fully specify one while deducing the other:

```
template<typename E> struct typed
    {

    template<std::size_t N> struct array
        {
        E data[N];
        };

    template<std::size_t N> array(const E (&data)[N]) -> array<N>;

    };

typed<float>::array float3a = {{0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f}};

auto float3b = typed<float>::array{{0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f}};

using floatArray = typed<float>::array;

auto float3c = floatArray{{0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f}};
```

This works with C++17.  C++20 features may make this obsolete or allow more convenient syntax.